# Return Array from Java to Python

Tags: java, python

Greetings i'm trying to return Array to Python from java(jar file) but only return array type string:

```
"['DIEGO ALBERTO AVILA', '', 'ACTIVO', 'N', 'OTRO', 'CEVALLOS', 'S/N','MOLINA']"
```

how i call to java from python:

```
import shlex, subprocess
import json

PARAMETRO = "1804464194001"
JAVA_CMD = 'java'
JAR_PATH = "catastro.jar"
command = [
    JAVA_CMD,
    '-jar',
    JAR_PATH,
    PARAMETRO
]
p = subprocess.Popen(
    command,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    #shell=True
)

result = p.communicate()[0]
print(result)
```

code Java:

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
....
try {
    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
        //data resultset
        String razonSocial = rs.getString("RAZON_SOCIAL");
        String nombreComercial = rs.getString("NOMBRE_COMERCIAL");
        String estadoContribuyente = rs.getString("ESTADO_CONTRIBUYENTE");
        String obligado = rs.getString("OBLIGADO");
        String tipoContribuyente = rs.getString("TIPO_CONTRIBUYENTE");
        String calle = rs.getString("CALLE");
        String numero = rs.getString("NUMERO");
        String interseccion = rs.getString("INTERSECCION");

        //data ArrayList
        result.add(razonSocial);
        result.add(nombreComercial);
        result.add(estadoContribuyente);
        result.add(obligado);
        result.add(tipoContribuyente);
        result.add(calle);
        result.add(numero);
        result.add(interseccion);

        //return result
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    conn.close();
    rs.close();
    st.close();
} catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

in this case i try using JSON but return the same type string don't array.
Maybe someone any suggest.

**update**

i try this(on python):

```
json.loads(result)
```

or this:

```
ast.literal_eval(result)
```

when i print this :

```
print(type(ast.literal_eval(result)))
```

get this error:

> File "invoque.py", line 23, in 
>       print(type(ast.literal_eval(ini_list)))   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
>       node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
>       return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)   File "", line 1
>       [LOACHAMIN AVILA DIEGO ALBERTO, , ACTIVO, N, PERSONAS NATURALES, MANUEL CAN, S/N, BRASIL]

but get the same type "string"  thanks..!!

Thanks..!!

Comment: Can you post output of `print(type(ast.literal_eval("['DIEGO ALBERTO AVILA', '', 'ACTIVO', 'N', 'OTRO', 'CEVALLOS', 'S/N','MOLINA']") ))`

Comment: ok, i post this print..!!

Answer (score 0):

How about converting the string back to list?

```
eval("['DIEGO ALBERTO AVILA', '', 'ACTIVO', 'N', 'OTRO', 'CEVALLOS', 'S/N','MOLINA']")
```

You might want to save it back to variable `result`

```
result = eval(result)
```

Comment: thanks but  when i use this and print "type(result)"..get type string

Comment: you need to update the post with how you have tried.`type(eval("['DIEGO ALBERTO AVILA', '', 'ACTIVO', 'N', 'OTRO', 'CEVALLOS', 'S/N','MOLINA']"))` will definitley return `list`